# How to avoid page-reload while using nebular menu-bar item's 'url' attribute

Tags: angular, url, menu, reload, nebular

I am using the nebular theme for my application. On the menu items, I have two things. Each item needs to be navigated using the URL attribute of the nebular menu.

**PROBLEM**:

The navigation works fine. **But, every time I click the item, refreshing happens**. I want to avoid that reloading. So kindly help me fix this.

Menu.ts:

```
import { NbMenuItem } from "@nebular/theme";

export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: "Orders",
    icon: "email-outline",
    url:"orders",
  },  
  {
    title: "Customers",
    icon: "person-outline",
    url:"customers",
  },
];
```

Routing-module.ts :

```
...
  {
    path: "",
    component: SidebarLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleGuard],
    data: { roles: [Role.admin] },
    children: [
      {
        path: "orders",
        component: AdminOrdersComponent,
      },
      {
        path: "customers",
        component: CustomerListComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
...
```

HTML:

```
<nb-layout windowMode>
  <nb-layout-header fixed>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </nb-layout-header>

  <nb-sidebar class="menu-sidebar" tag="menu-sidebar" responsive>
    <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
  </nb-sidebar>

  <nb-layout-column>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

Comment: Show your HTML .

Comment: Wait  I'll add it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The API documentation](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/menu/api#nbmenuitem) tells you yu need to use `[link]` for router links, not `[url]`. So change the `url` key to `link`.

Comment: I have tried that. If I use 'link', navigation is not happening. I don't know why?

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] of it

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have identified the problem with my headerModules routing. That routing overrides the 'link' attribute route in this nebular menu. So I fixed it.Thank you for your response